# OCR confusing zero with "o" - how to specify zero or letter "o" in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using OCR to read images and PDFs and afterwards I try to extract certain numbers out of it.
In some cases, the OCR algorithms read zero as the letter "o".

The OCR gave me this string:

```
Siabicbnenl| 033-7 | _o3300.81086 42000.000002 20852.301017 1 82510000030694



Prerfasa afesad
```

If the OCR read it right it would have ben like this:

```
Siabicbnenl| 033-7 | _03300.81086 42000.000002 20852.301017 1 82510000030694



Prerfasa afesad
```

I want to catch that `03300.81086 42000.000002 20852.301017 1 82510000030694`

My pattern `(?s)\d{5}\.?\d{5}.*?\d{5}\.?\d{6}.*?\d{5}\.?\d{6}.*?\d.*?\d{14}` would have worked fine if the OCR had read it right, but here I got in contact with a new situation:

**OCR confused zero with "o"**

Is there a way to fix my pattern in order to also consider "o" as zero or I will need to make an `if 'didnt find anything': str.replace("o",0)` and run it again?

Comment: Treating `o` as `0` isn't going to fix this - there's data on the completely wrong line.

Comment: Actually the pattern considers it and that's the reason it is not a prob, but yes, it could be clearer. I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character class `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` for ASCII input. If you want to include the lower-case "o" as well, you could use `[0-9o]` everywhere you use `\d` now.

If you expect that the input contains digit characters other than the ASCII 0 to 9, you can combine `\d` with `o` in a (capturing) group with two alternatives: `(\d|o)`. If you like you can make it non-capturing, too: `(?:\d|o)`.

Comment: The character class `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` *for ASCII-only text*.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks, I didn't know that. Might be good to know at some time.

Comment: If I would like to also include capital "o" ("O") it would be [0-9oO]?

Comment: @abutremutante Exactly.